# In Powershell, how to create a directory using IP address into a remote computer using do-while loop

Tags: powershell

Please help me. I'm trying trying to create a PowerShell script using do-while loop as follows:

1. Ask user for folder name (foldername) and target IP Address (targetipaddress)
2. If "foldername" does not exist, then create "foldername" in "C:\" drive
3. Using "targetipaddress" as the part of target path, copy the contents from a sub folder of network drive path,"S:\" and paste into the "foldername" in the "C:\" path.
4. If user enters "quit", then script finishes.

My code below:

```
$var = "welcome to IP address and folder creation world"
echo $var

# create foldername until user type "quit"
$output = (command)
do { 

$foldername = Read-Host "enter folder name "
$targetipaddress = Read-Host "enter target ip address "

# create folder name only if it does not exist
function createFolder {
$path = "\\$targetipaddress\C$\$foldername "
If (!(Test-Path $path))
{ 
      New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force $path
}

} # end of function createFolder

# copy contents from a sub folder of a network drive path and
# and paste them onto "C:\" drive path using "targetipaddress" and "foldername"

function copyContents {
 Copy-Item S:\sourcefolder\subfolder\*.*  \\$targetipaddress\C$\$foldername\ -Recurse
 }

 } while ($foldername = "quit") # end of do-while loop
```

Comment: Don't forget to ask your question.

Comment: You define functions **inside the do..while** but never **use** them?

Comment: hi LotPings, I'm confused if do-while loop is the right approach. Maybe it is "do loop until ". Thanks

Comment: Ben the problem is that you (re-)define the functions with every iteration of the do while. But you never **use** the function by invoking it by it's name. So move the function definition outside the do..while and use the name **or** remove the definition with it's curly braces as it has no advantage here. This is pretty basic stuff in any language.

Comment: `($foldername = "quit")`: That's not how you compare for equality in PowerShell. Use `-eq`, not `=`. There are other [comparison operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators).

Comment: Thank you Mike, LotPings, Bill. Appreaciate the advices.

Answer (score 1):

See below for a working example, read carefully and compare this one with your own.

Some of the problems / changes.

- echo? it should be write-host
- unnecessary and unused functions.
- $output = (command), it does nothing.
- do while, i like to use while($true) and break out of it.
- optional, error handling.
- powershell does not use = (i believe you meant ==) for equels logic but -eq
- a few other problems / changes.

some reading materials:

- Comparison Operators See link from Mike Sherrill 'Cat Recall'
- [Continue](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/05/09/powershell-looping-the-continue-statement/)
- [Break](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/05/07/powershell-looping-basics-of-the-break/)

If you get an error with this code please post the inputs voor $source, $foldername, $targetipaddress and $path and i will look at it.

Code:

```
clear-host #clears your console, optional.
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop" #prevents al lot of posible disasters from happening.

Write-Host "welcome to IP address and folder creation world" #Powershell way of writing to the console.

$source = "S:\sourcefolder\subfolder\*"
#$source = "C:\source\*" i used this for testing on my local machine.

# create foldername until user type "quit"
While ($true){ 

    "

    "#Add some white space between the questions.

    $foldername = Read-Host "enter folder name "
    If ($foldername -eq "quit") {break} #exit the while loop

    $targetipaddress = Read-Host "enter target ip address " #you could use a hostname to.

    $path = "\\$targetipaddress\C$\$foldername"

    #if connection to targetipaddress fails then abort.
    if(!(Test-Connection $targetipaddress -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) #look at the ! it means it should be false.
    {
        Write-Warning "Could not connect to '$targetipaddress'"
        continue #goes back to the begining of the while loop.
    }

    #if path does not exist try to create it.
    if(!(Test-Path $path)) #look at the ! it means it should be false.
    {
        try { New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path (Split-Path -Parent $path) -Name $foldername | Out-null } #Out-null prevenst unwanted console output.
        catch {
            Write-Warning "Could not create folder '$foldername' on '$targetipaddress'"
            continue #goes back to the begining of the while loop.
        }
    }

    #try to copy files.
    try { Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination $path -Recurse -Force }
    catch {
        Write-Warning "An Error occured while copying the files from '$source' to '$path'"
        continue #goes back to the begining of the while loop.
    }

    #if all goes well then tell them ;)
    Write-Host "files copied successfully from $source to $path"

}
```

Comment: You are awesome, SteloNLD. Thank you. I'm trying this soon. Thanks all again

Comment: SteloNLD, ran it locally in my computer and works great.   Thank you.        
   When user enters an ip that is not reachable, the loop returns to ask to enter folder name.                                             
   Question:  when does  the following is obeyed?                      
    #if connection to targetipaddress fails then abort."?                                                
    if(!(Test-Connection $targetipaddress -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) 
    #look at the ! it means it should be false.

Comment: Yes, the part after ' #if connection to targetipaddress fails then abort ' wil reset the loop it should show a warning saying: ' Could not connect to '$targetipaddress' '